# Display tooltip on UITableView in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I was wondering if anyone has tried it. I need to show a tooltip within a table view when the user selects a word in the row's text.

Can you please help me or suggest any way for this?

Thanks in advance!!!!!!

Comment: you have to keep behind UIView or UIButton of each word.When you calling UITouchBegan event method then on touchCount =1 ,it you have to search all kind of data related to that word. After searching data you have to create dynamically UITextView near the word.And show it.

Comment: The above process is only for valid for limited word only.

Comment: tooltip cha concept implement karane kup kathin aahe aahe.....

Comment: Thanks for your help!!! I know its difficult but I want to know any other relevant way to implement this. I will try your this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In each cell add a UIView (be it a UITextView, UIImageView or whatever, in fact you can add plenty of additional subviews to it). Say you call it "tooltipView".

Now when user selects text, all you have to do is position (move around) that view near the selection (or where the user touched the row) and set the relative information. To track the selection, you can simply override the `- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method of your cell class and keep checking the `point` variable and corresponding `event`.

Comment: oh!!! it is also one of the way for creating that question sender wants, But it has also be limitation that i commented before in which we want to keep an UIView behind the each word.If there is 100 word then you have to create 100 UIViews.